# Use markdown to generate definitions and abbr list in one

Tags: python, sublimetext2, markdown

I am writing some pretty long documentation for work. I would like to know if there was a way I could combine/collapse the definitions list and abbreviations into one list. For example:

Instead of:

```
HTML
: Hyper text markup language blah blah blah asdf asdf asdf.
```

&

```
*[HTML]: Hyper text markup language
```

Is there a way I can write something to do both while only having to write one of those lines?

The main problem is the abbreviation list doesn't show up as a list, it is removed from the visible text. and the definition list doesn't label things as abbreviations.

There are a lot of acronyms and abbreviations, I really think its a waste of file size and effort to have to do both.

Any ideas? Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

You could write a script (could be implemented as a plugin but doesn't have to be) to take the definition list and generate the list. You could also use a snippet. The downside of this being one will follow the other. Of course, depending on where you place the cursor to do the next entry, the order of the list may just be reversed.

```
<snippet>
    <content><![CDATA[
${1:Abberviation/Acronym}
: ${2:name} ${3:description}

${4}

*[${1:Abberviation/Acronym}]: ${2:name}

]]></content>
    <tabTrigger>entry</tabTrigger>
    <scope>text.html.markdown</scope>
</snippet>
```

With the above snippet, you can tab through each entry point. After typing the definition, pressing tab will put you in between the entries. You can remove that if you would like.

Comment: Ya, I think I just might end up writing a quick python script to duplicate the data for me. I think that would be the fastest and most consistent way.